# Can I use Apple TV to record the use of an App on my iPad?

Tags: mac, display, iphone, screen-recorder, appletv

I am wondering if I can use Apple TV to mirror an App that runs on my iPad 3 to the Television, and then record it in a format that I can edit on my Mac.

The point of doing this is to create a video preview of an Game/App that I am developing (I need a screencast with many frames of the game and using the softwarae like screencast.com or QuickTime to record the screen from my Mac makes me loose some frames).

Comment: I don't believe Apple TV has any record capabilities. Maybe if you pipe the output to something that could record the video but their might be encryption issues.

Comment: That's soo bad :(.. I need to find a way to record things. For instance my SONY BRAVIA computer can record things but on an HD that is encrypted and so, once I try to read the APP VIDEO that I mirrowed using the mirrowing cable that I bought (For quiet a lot) on my computer I cannot see it. Those anti piracy things make the products unusable for my normal and legal use. It makes me want to learn how to hack those things..